# makefile with header files

Tags: c, makefile

i am trying to create a makefile for my program and for some reason it simply doesnt work with header files, i have searched the web and tried dozens of makefiles and orders but cant make it work. i have a simple main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("the number of params: %d\n" ,argc);
    p();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and i have the header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int p();
```

and the func.c

```
#include "func.h"
int p(){
    printf("p");
}
```

my makefiles currently looks like this:

```
check: Excersize1.c func.c
     gcc -o check Excersize1.c func.c
```

the problem is that when the file check is created it doesnt run the function p(), the only output is "the number of..."

any help will be appritiated.

NOTICE: the code works great and can be used as an example to the use of header files and the creation of makefile that supports them.

Comment: Are you SURE it's not printing `p`?  Note that your `printf()` in the `p()` function does not include a newline, so there will be no newline printed afterward.  This means that your prompt will be appended to it.  Maybe you just aren't noticing that the `p` is there, at the beginning of your prompt?  If you don't get a compilation or linker error, then the `p` *MUST* be printed.

Comment: @MadScientist you are right sir! i missed it. thank you very much!!

Comment: Why aren't you returning anything from `int p()` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that didn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the header, your problem is that the standard output is line buffered. That means that you are not guaranteed that output will actually be written before you write an end of line character. Your `printf()` in `main()` has an line end `'\n'`, it appears immediately. Your output in `p()` does not, and there is no other output happening subsequently.

Try changing your func.h to

```
#include "func.h"
int p(){
    printf("p\n");
}
```

and you should see a lonely `p` on a line of its own in the output.